# Format weather integration in xmobar

Tags: xmobar

I am trying to configure the Run Weather integration in my `.xmobarrc` file.  Currently I have it working this way, this is the one line I need help with:

```
[ Run Weather "KMGW" ["-t", "temp <tempF>F","-L","64","-H","77","--normal","green","--high","red","--low","lightblue" ] 36000
```

...this works fine but I am trying to add another parameter for instance `skyCondition`.  Could someone format it correctly for me on what it should be?  If you could possibly test this for me on your own xmobar, that would be helpful before answering.  I tried a few different ways but can't figure this one out with the doublequotes.  Thanks.